# SQL combining two queries inside the same table without a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

A table, Employee has columns EmployeeID, Salary.
How do I find the EmployeeIDs which have a salary greater than the average salary?

Using Subqueries:

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary > (SELECT AVG(Salary)
                 FROM Employee);
```

Is it possible using joins?
Is any other method possible?

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want to have a query without a subquery in this case? I'm sensing an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @TT because all subqueries be also solved using joins?

Comment: No that is not the case. If you would rewrite to join with "something", that something would be a derived table, which is a subquery that takes the place of a table in a join clause. Still, I don't see a reason why you would want to write it differently. IMO the way it is written in your question is the correct way to go about expressing this in SQL.

Answer (score 6):

It seems really silly to me to write it this way, but here it is without any subqueries:

```
SELECT a.EmployeeID
FROM Employee a
CROSS JOIN Employee b
GROUP BY a.EmployeeID, a.Salary
HAVING a.Salary > AVG(b.Salary)
```

Comment: So normally, one **should** use a subquery?

Comment: I've just never seen it written any way other than the subquery (either the way you wrote it originally, or the way @StanislavL wrote it in their answer), so those seem more familiar to me. It's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Maybe SQL Server can optimize to the same execution plan, though I doubt it. This will probably really cross join two tables giving the square of the number of rows, having to group it by two fields etc. Props for coming up with this, but I wouldn't touch it with a ten foot pole.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM Employee, (SELECT AVG(Salary) avg_savary
                 FROM Employee) sal
WHERE Salary > sal.avg_savary;
```

Move the average salary calculation to FROM to calculate it once. BTW most of moder DB can optimize your query to calculate it once.

Comment: This uses a subquery, no?

Comment: @JacobH is it possible without joins or subqueries?

Comment: @JacobH technically you are right - my answer has a subquery. Josh answer is technically correct no subqueries but much slower.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT EmployeeID,salary AVG(salary) OVER() avg_salary FROM Employee) 
WHERE Salary >avg_salary
```

Comment: No i use a Windows function instead
Unless you mean a derived table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID FROM Employee e
JOIN
(
 SELECT avg(Salary) as Salary FROM Employee
) e1
ON e.Salary > e1.Salary
```

Comment: This has a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @AverageSalary as Money
Select @AverageSalary = AVG(Salary) From Employee
Select * from Employee Where Salary > @AverageSalary
```